# 好き【すき】でした。付き【つき】合って【あって】ください。

Tags: usage, tense

I found many people say 好きでした when they actually mean 好きです. I think it is short for ずっと好きでした. I know ずっと～していた and ずっと～している can well mean the same, but I still do not know the nuance between 好きでした and 好きです.

---

The question is about the difference between 好きでした and 好きです. The following do not have to be relevant, but I hope it can inspire discussions and answers.

My first thought is that ずっと may be the culprit. It is often used with た even when る is possible and more logically correct. ずっと is often used with していた and している. The two expressions often happen to be interchangeable. And I think compared with している, していた often implies the process/action/state is *interrupted* or *something else* happens in the meanwhile, like in

> 彼女に電話をかけようと考えていたところ、彼女の方から、電話をかけて来た

My another observation is that た is often used to in *experience-based* expressions. It seems that た (as well as the particle だ, adjective ending い) is especially common in expressions involving expressing emotions, and る is rare in this usage. All following sentences are *stative*, very different from verbs. I assume 好きでした has something to do with it.

1. Impressions, reports

> (After watching) いい最終回だった
>
> (Looking out the window, then coming back and saying) 誰もいなかった

2. Feelings

> (Hearing good news) よかった
>
> (After the issue is solved) ありがとうございました

3. Something between 1 and 2

> (When you finally got to see someone) 会いたかった
>
> (Same as above) 待っていました

There are many other usages of た, but I do not think they are particularly relevant.

I feel that 好きでした is more or less the same as 会いたかった and 待っていました. Unlike case 1 and 2, both sentences can be used with ずっと, which is similar to 好きでした. But it can be argued that the uses of た in both sentences are logical, because both imply 会えた so the speaker is no longer 会いたい or 待っている. Nevertheless, I think 好きでした conveys the same level of emotional intensity as 会いたかった and 待っていました, if you compare them with 待たせたな, 遅い、すごく待った. I think people say 愛してる rather than 愛してた probably because 片思いのほうが辛い.

*To emphasize the feeling over a long past period of time*, is this the reason that makes た often fit better with ずっと?

Comment: 「好きでした。付き合ってください」 sounds very weird if comes out of nowhere. However, 「好きだったんです。付き合ってください」 seems to work. I can't say why yet.

Comment: @broccoliforest, thank you. I didn't know that. Does **ずっと前から**好きでした。付き合って下さい sound any better?

Comment: Oh, this one has no problem.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between 好きでした and 好きです is somewhat subtle. It depends on whether or not the action/event/whatever being described is a one time event or an ongoing action. For example, If you liked a concert you would probably say 好きでした (or, if you wanted to sound even more natural, 面白｛おもしろ｝かった -- It was interesting). If you like studying Japanese, you would say 日本語を勉強｛べんきょう｝するのが好きです. It's similar to the English, "I *liked* that movie." as opposed to "I *like* that movie." Both are correct, but in Japanese you would slightly prefer the past tense if you're talking about a single event.

---

For 「よかった, いい最終回だった」, this is actually two independent clauses so the adverb ずっと wouldn't work. The 良{よ}かった is saying, "That was great." If you wanted to use ずっと, you would put if before the verb and make the verb past tense. For example, この道{みち}をずっと行った (I went all the way down this road).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I edited my question to make it clearer. The case of verbs is much more obvious than adjectives. I don't think 好き is a *one time event*, but I assume you mean the same as my term *experience-based*. I think your explanation mostly aligns with my examples in case 1.

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to current answers/comments. 
It could also be a Hokkaido thing. When I lived and worked in Sapporo, some people (mostly 50 and older) would use a similar past tense. For e.g., I might get a phone call where the other person might say "もしもし、佐藤でした" instead of "もしもし、佐藤です"

you might find more details by googling "北海道弁 過去形"