# Is this correct?

Tags: grammar, translation

そうだったのオレはてっきり

Translation: I was right, there's no mistaking it

Comment: this is pretty difficult to translate without context but your version sounds wrong.

Answer (score 2):

そうだったの means "Is that so!", "Now I understand". This phrase ～だと思った probably would follow after オレはてっきり. So it means "I certainly thought that ～".

Comment: この「そうだったの」は多分 "Is that so?" の方が自然だと思います。[「発見の"た"」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40888/5010)というそうです。