# そうです or そうでした for sentences that end with でしたか

Tags: word-choice, tense

> 山下先生のせんこうはれきしでしたか。

To answer the above sentence, would the sentences below be acceptable?

1. はい、そうでした。
2. はい、そうです。

Is 1 the only acceptable answer since the question is in past tense?

Answer (score 5):

Both are possible, and the choice will depend on the context and the mood. (Why is the first question in the past tense?) If you are objectively saying "Yes (that *is* right)", そうです is the natural choice. But そうでした is also fine in the following situations:

- When you are vividly recalling him at some point in the past (e.g., he is already a dead person and you remember the lecture he gave to you)
- When you want to somehow emphasize his current major is no longer history
- When the question reminded you of that fact ([modal-た](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40888/5010))

Answer (score 1):

I would say

> はい、そうです。

because it means `Yes, that is correct`.
Answering with `はい、そうでした` may be ok but it sounds a bit strange to me as it sounds like `Yes, that was correct`.

Other answers I may hear people say would be

> はい、れきしでした
>
> はい、れきしです