# On the interaction between tense harmony and factivity in (dialects of) Japanese

Tags: tense, subordinate-clauses, semantics, relative-tense

First of all, I'm a linguist asking a VERY technical question, so I'll do my best to make myself understood. I'd prefer if **commenters made it clear what their level of Japanese is (native, advanced, etc.).**

---

English and Japanese are said to differ in that the former has tense harmony, whereas the latter doesn't. Having tense harmony means that if a main verb and its subordinate are both in the past tense, then the whole clause **must** be interpreted as referring to two **simultaneous** past events. For instance, (1) means that at some time *t* in the past Taro said that Hanako was in Seattle at *t* (while he was in Tokyo speaking).

```
(1) Taro said that Hanako was in Seattle.
```

Japanese works differently. The literal, word-by-word translation of (1) into Japanese means that at some time *t* in the past Taro said that Hanako was in Seattle at *t'*, for some time *t'* < *t* (in particular, Hanako could've already left Seattle when Taro made his statement):

```
(2) 太郎は、花子がシアトルにいたと言った (back-shifted interpretation)
```

In order to get a proper translation of (1) you need a **present tense verb** in the subordinate clause:

```
(3) 太郎は、花子がシアトルにいると言った (simultaneous interpretation)
```

This shows that Japanese doesn't have tense harmony: when the main verb and its subordinate are both in the past, you don't get "harmony" or "simultaneity"; you get a back-shifted interpretation in which the event referred to by the subordinate verb is a past event relative to the event referred to by the main verb.

**However, it is claimed that for some Japanese speakers the "simultaneous reading" is admissible when the main verb is a factive verb** [What is a factive verb? A factive verb presupposes that its subordinate clause is true: *know* is factive because "she knows that it's raining" presupposes that it's actually raining; on the other hand, *believe* is not factive because "she believes that it's raining" doesn't presuppose that it's raining... she could be dead wrong!].

```
(4) 太郎は自分が癌だったと知っていた
```

Does this accord with your intuition? Do you interpret (4) to mean that Taro knew at *t* that he had cancer at *t*, or do you get a back-shifted reading? Are there any more examples like this one? (I know very little of Japanese, but I'm told other factive verbs are 
後悔する, 忘れる, etc.).

Comment: `(1) means that at some time t in the past Taro said that Hanako was in Seattle at t (while he was in Tokyo speaking)` I think English can have the back-shifted interpretation, too. Take this scenario: Bob and Alice are trying to remember if Hanako was in Seattle last year. Bob calls a mutual friend Taro, who confirms (at time _t_) that Hanako was indeed in Seattle for a marathon at the time (_t'_). Then Bob relays this information to Alice via (1). _t_ happens during the phone call, and _t'_ is one year ago.

Answer (score 4):

(Disclaimer: I am a native Japanese speaker, but not an expert of language)

- (a) 太郎は自分が癌だと知っていた
- (b) 太郎は自分が癌だったと知っていた

I feel there is a slight difference in meaning between (a) and (b).

Sentence (a) is the natural choice in most cases because of the [relative-tense](/questions/tagged/relative-tense) rule you have described. But (b) may be used to describe certain situations:

1. Other people around Taro had known about his disease (at *t'*) before Taro himself learned the fact (at *t*). That is, the speaker is somehow emphasizing 'Taro has a cancer' was already past (*t'*) news to many when Taro finally recognized it (*t*).
2. Taro was recalling a certain past event (symptom) that had made himself worry about his disease. For example, if you experienced bloody stool last month and a physician told you today "You have a colon cancer", then you may say 僕は癌だっ**た**のか! ("So, I have/had a cancer(, that explains a lot)!") Japanese often uses た/だ to describe something in the present/future for various reasons (See [discovery/recall-た](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/another-function-of-the-ta-form-discovery-and-recall/) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40888/5010)). You cannot say this if you were asymptomatic.

Either way, I would say 癌だった in (b) is somehow related to something in the relative past (*t'*), so some sort of back-shifting is involved. But saying 癌だった does not mean he has recovered from cancer at the point of *t*.

(To be honest, I'm not sure how a "factive verb" comes into play; this is probably the first time I heard such a verb category regarding the Japanese language, and no other questions here contain such a phrase. Do you have an article for that?)