# Main usages of the た-Form

Tags: usage, て-form, past

A couple of weeks ago I learned in my course the usage of the て-Form which were:

- Chaining verbs together , all of which are written in the で-Form and the last one is written with the polite form. The last verb can indicate if the action happened in the past or present/future (ます／、ました)
- Asking someone to do something, for example: **まって**　ください
- Saying that you are currently doing an action: アメリカに　**すんで**　います

I want to learn about the other usages of the た-Form since I know that both forms are written very similarly.
I tried to search online about the Usage and no luck.
All I know about it is that it's the plain past form.

So, in practice, all I know is the I can write in two ways something I did in the past:

- ビルを　のみました.
- ビルを　のんだ.

My main question is what are the main usages of the た-Form? 
Is it like the て-Form ?
Is there a site that explains it more deeply ?

Comment: I think that the て-Form has so many usages because it turns the verb in an adverb in a way, whereas the た-Form is just the conjugation for a verb into its past form. There are grammar points such as たほうが that use the た-Form without the "past" meaning, but they include more elements than just a verb ending in the た-Form

Comment: As jarmanso7 says た is nowhere near as flexible as て. I can only think of one other use, which is described in this link: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40733/non-conventional-usage-of-the-past-tense/40888#40888

Answer (score 1):

According to Kunihiro there are 9 usages for ーた form.

1. A situation completed in the past or that lasted for a certain length of time in the past:

> `Haha ni tegami o kai-TA` ‘I WROTE a letter to my mother.’

2. Habitual repetition in the past:

> `Ano koro wa yoku undoo si-TA` ‘I USED TO EXERCISE frequently in those
> days.’

3. A situation that occurred under a certain circumstance in the
   past:

> `Kaeru to sugu ni te o arat-TA` ‘I WOULD WASH my hands
> immediately after I got home.’

4. A situation that materialized in the past and still exists:

> `Ookiku nat-TA ne` ‘You’VE  GROWN, haven’t you?’

5. Sudden discovery that a certain state has continuously existed
   (the so-called TA form  of discovery; a special case of (4):

> `A, soko ni i-TA no` ‘Oh, there you ARE!’

6. Sudden recalling of a future event or plan that the speaker has known as definite:

> `A,  asita siken ga at-TA` ‘Oh, I HAVE an exam tomorrow!’

7. A request for hearer’s confirmation of a fact (normally only in
   questions):

> `Anata wa donata desi-TA ka` ‘Who ARE you?’

8. Proclamation  or  assertion  of  the  realization  of  a
   situation  which  has  not  been  realized:

> `Yosi kat-TA` ‘All right, (I’m sold) I’LL BUY it!’

9. A command:

> `Doi-TA, doi-TA` ‘STEP back! STEP back!’

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments a little research, I am able to assemble a humble answer. 
These are the main usages of the た-Form:

- 1st one is the obvious, which is the option to say a verb in it's past tense plainly.

  > this raises a personal question **(which I do not want to discuss here)** which is: can I chain multiple た-Forms like the て-Form?
- 2nd is saying "probably did something" by doing this -> [た-Form + だろ／でしょう]. 
  here's an example of a site I visit often to get a [verb's full conjugation(Drink 
  Example)](http://www.japaneseverbconjugator.com/VerbDetails.asp?txtVerb=%E9%A3%B2%E3%82%80) -> 飲んだだろう ／ 飲んだでしょう
- 3rd is taken from [user3856370's comment link page](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40733/non-conventional-usage-of-the-past-tense/40888#40888); "Discovery and Recall".
  For a "Discovery Expression", we can conjugate ある／いる to the た-Form to add a 
  "discovery" sound to it (Just as you hear in anime the verb 見つけ**た**！).

Summary:
I think that た-Form, as said by jarmanso7, is much less flexible since "the た-Form is just the conjugation for a verb into its past form", where's the て-Form is mainly used to chain various expressions [(This video,at 0:23, explains what the て-Form is)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nsBeKXmS-yc).
It has no direct (what so ever) indication about the time the verb occurred.
Rather, the nonて-Form that is attached to it, indicates the time and meaning.

- 食べて ください ("Please eat" expression)
- (私は) 食べて 飲みました ("I ate and drank", the last verb indicating that the "eating" was done in the past).

In short, the て-Form was meant for modification, where's the た-Form is mainly used for past plain tense.

Comment: I recommend you to make a new post if you have new questions, rather than asking a new question in an answer. You can always add a link to the new question in this answer for reference.

Comment: Oh, about if you multiple chain multiple Ta-Forms ? 
I know, sorry.
It wasn't really meant to ask a new question, but provide my own thoughts on the subject.
I'll hide it to not mislead the purpose of my answer

Comment: Why does this answer contain a spoiler?

Comment: @istrasci for the reason discussed in the previous comments. It should probably be edited out.