# How to differentiate between the meanings of けり?

Tags: classical-japanese

けり has 2 meanings: 過去 and 詠嘆. Is there some sort of trick to find out which one is being used? (besides context, of course)

Comment: This question is too broad... can you give us an example of when those two terms might feel ambiguous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 詠嘆のけり is placed at the end of the main clause.
- 詠嘆のけり takes the 終止形 form unless 係り結び is involved.
- 詠嘆のけり appears more often in quotes than in narrative parts.
- なりけり is always 詠嘆.
- In haiku/waka, けり is almost always 詠嘆.

<sub>By the way, I feel 詠嘆のけり is somewhat close to [発見のタ in modern Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40888/5010).</sub>

References:

- [「き・けり」 - 古典文法](https://www.kotenbunpou.com/%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E/%E3%81%8D-%E3%81%91%E3%82%8A/)
- [助動詞 けり の詠嘆と過去の見分け方おしえてください！](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14145621604)